# extract all words between two match words

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I Have a single line as follows, I need all the words between **select** and **Done**

```
 vertical on; select blah blah blah contains all special characters including /*?&;  Done
```

Comment: Is this in a pipeline? A file? A variable?

Comment: could you have `something select blah selection foo Done`? or `something else is done and Done`?

Comment: @jeff compelte line is stored in variable. its solved now. tq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using bash regular expression would give (assuming the line in a variable):

```
$ line="vertical on; select blah blah blah contains all special characters including /*?&;  Done"
$ [[ "$line" =~ select(.*)Done ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
blah blah blah contains all special characters including /*?&;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sed -e 's/select\(.*\)Done/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 sed -e 's/.*select//;s/Done.*//'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE):

```
(?<=word1).*?(?=word2)
```

Applying the above pattern with GNU `grep`:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=select).*?(?=Done)' <<< ' vertical on; select blah blah blah contains all special characters including /*?&;  Done'
 blah blah blah contains all special characters including /*?&;
```

---

**Explanation**

- `(?<=word1)`: Match `word1` *before* the current position but don't include it in the result.
- `.*?`: Match any string.
- `(?=word2)`: Match `word2` *after* the current position but don't include it in the result.

The `(?<=word1)` and `(?=word2)` patterns are collectively known as [**lookaround**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). This feature is not supported by POSIX engines (BRE and ERE) so you need a more powerful engine (such as PCRE).

Comment: thank you nxnev, little correction in my question. whole line is stored in variable. how to pass variable to it ....its in shell scripting i need it. thank you in advance

Comment: @sachin_ghagare All you need is to pass the content of that variable to `grep`'s standard input. With Bash: `grep -Po '(?<=select).*?(?=Done)' <<< "${var}"` (note that there will be a trailing newline). With any other POSIX shell (Bash included): `printf '%s' "${var}" | grep -Po '(?<=select).*?(?=Done)'` (there's no trailing newline by default, but you can add it with `\n` in the first argument of `printf`).

Comment: @sachin_ghagare Also, if this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark beside the answer. Or wait to see if another answer better solves the problem. Whatever works for you.